# iOS Swift - EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on certain devices

Tags: ios, swift, crash, exc-bad-instruction

I'm very new to Swift and iOS development but I've come across a bug that is causing my app to crash when running on the following devices:

iPhone 4S
iPhone 5
iPad 2
iPad Retina

Here is the code that is being flagged up:

```
// bin2dec - converts binary string into decimal string
func bin2dec(input: String) -> String {
    var counter = countElements(input)
    var digit: Character
    var power = 1
    var result = 0

    while counter > 0 {
        digit = input[advance(input.startIndex, counter-1)]

        switch digit {
        case "0":
            result += 0
        case "1":
            result += 1 * power
        default:
            power = power / 2
            break
        }
        counter--
        power *= 2
    }
    return "\(result)"
}
```

and the error is:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What input kills it, and at what line?

Comment: Oh yes of course, inside the switch on the line with case "0": and when it receives a full 32bit string e.g. (11111111111111111111111111111111)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, iPad 2, iPad Retina are 32-bit devices, where `Int`
is a 32-bit integer. Therefore starting with

```
var power = 1
```

and then calling

```
power *= 2
```

32 times will overflow and cause an exception. In Swift, integer arithmetic does not silently "wrap around" as in (Objective-)C,
unless you explicitly use the "overflow operators" `&*`, `&+` etc.

Possible solutions:

- Use `Int64` instead of `Int`.
- Avoid the final multiplication of `power` (whose result is not
  needed).

Note that there are simpler methods to convert a string of binary
digits to a number, see for example [How to convert a binary to decimal in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790660/how-to-convert-a-binary-to-decimal-in-swift).

Comment: Might also be worthwhile to note that on current 64-bit devices, the problem still occurs, but with strings twice as long.